# Ordering of GitHub operations when matrix is involved

Tags: github-actions

I have a Github action that should

1. Build a number of executable artifacts for various platforms
2. Create a Github release where all of those artifacts are stored and associated with the release

I started with this

```
name: "Release"

on:
  push:
    branches: "*"
    tags:
      - "*"

permissions:
  contents: write

jobs:
  release:
    name: Release
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.target.host || 'ubuntu-latest' }}
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        go-version: ["1.21.x"]
        target:
          - os: linux
          - os: windows
            ext: .exe
          - os: freebsd
          - os: android
          - os: darwin
            host: macos-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Go
        uses: actions/setup-go@v4
        with:
          # cache:
          # - description: Used to specify whether caching is needed. Set to true, if you'd like to enable caching.
          # default: false
          go-version-file: "go.mod"
          cache-dependency-path: |
            go.sum

      - name: Install Fyne-cross
        # working-directory: fyne-cross
        run: go install github.com/fyne-io/fyne-cross@latest

      # attempt to use "go install" but fallback to "go get"
      - name: Install Fyne
        run: |
          go install fyne.io/fyne/v2/cmd/fyne@latest ||
          go get fyne.io/fyne/v2/cmd/fyne@latest

      - name: Install Podman
        if: ${{ runner.os == 'macos' }}
        run: |
          brew install podman
          podman machine init
          podman machine start

      - name: "Build MastoTool (${{ matrix.target.os }}, ${{ matrix.go-version }})"
        run: |
          fyne-cross \
            ${{ matrix.target.os }} \
            ${{ matrix.target.args }} \
            -name mastotool${{ matrix.target.ext }} \
            -app-id com.github.PaulWaldo.mastotool

      - uses: ncipollo/release-action@v1
        with:
          artifacts: fyne-cross/dist/**/mastotool*
```

This method did not work, as each build in the matrix tried to create a release when it was done and Github complained that the release already existed.

I then tried to make them separate ordered jobs, but that did not work either.  While the artifacts were created by the `artifacts` job, the `release` job did not see them.

```
name: "Release"

on:
  push:
    branches: "*"
    tags:
      - "*"

permissions:
  contents: write

jobs:
  artifacts:
    name: Create Artifacts
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.target.host || 'ubuntu-latest' }}
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        go-version: ["1.21.x"]
        target:
          - os: linux
          - os: windows
            ext: .exe
          - os: freebsd
          - os: android
          # Darwin not working right now
          # - os: darwin
          #   host: macos-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Go
        uses: actions/setup-go@v4
        with:
          # cache:
          # - description: Used to specify whether caching is needed. Set to true, if you'd like to enable caching.
          # default: false
          go-version-file: "go.mod"
          cache-dependency-path: |
            go.sum

      - name: Install Fyne-cross
        # working-directory: fyne-cross
        run: go install github.com/fyne-io/fyne-cross@latest

      # attempt to use "go install" but fallback to "go get"
      - name: Install Fyne
        run: |
          go install fyne.io/fyne/v2/cmd/fyne@latest ||
          go get fyne.io/fyne/v2/cmd/fyne@latest

      - name: Install Podman
        if: ${{ runner.os == 'macos' }}
        run: |
          brew install podman
          podman machine init
          podman machine start

      - name: "Build MastoTool (${{ matrix.target.os }}, ${{ matrix.go-version }})"
        run: |
          fyne-cross \
            ${{ matrix.target.os }} \
            ${{ matrix.target.args }} \
            -name mastotool${{ matrix.target.ext }} \
            -app-id com.github.PaulWaldo.mastotool

  release:
    name: Create Release
    needs: artifacts
    runs-on: "ubuntu-latest"
    steps:
      - run: ls -lR fyne-cross/dist
      - uses: ncipollo/release-action@v1
        with:
          artifacts: fyne-cross/dist/**/mastotool*
```

What would be the appropriate way to pause until all the artifacts are created and then create the release?

### Update

the answer by @Azeem was spot on.  Here is my updated working job

```
name: "Release"

on:
  push:
    branches: "*"
    tags:
      - "*"

permissions:
  contents: write

jobs:
  artifacts:
    name: Create Artifacts
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.target.host || 'ubuntu-latest' }}
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        go-version: ["1.21.x"]
        target:
          - os: linux
          - os: windows
            ext: .exe
          - os: freebsd
          - os: android
          # Darwin not working right now
          # - os: darwin
          #   host: macos-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Go
        uses: actions/setup-go@v4
        with:
          cache:
            true
          go-version-file: "go.mod"
          cache-dependency-path: |
            go.sum

      - name: Install Fyne-cross
        # working-directory: fyne-cross
        run: go install github.com/fyne-io/fyne-cross@latest

      # attempt to use "go install" but fallback to "go get"
      - name: Install Fyne
        run: |
          go install fyne.io/fyne/v2/cmd/fyne@latest ||
          go get fyne.io/fyne/v2/cmd/fyne@latest

      - name: Install Podman
        if: ${{ runner.os == 'macos' }}
        run: |
          brew install podman
          podman machine init
          podman machine start

      - name: "Build MastoTool (${{ matrix.target.os }}, ${{ matrix.go-version }})"
        # Place build targets in "/home/runner/work/mastotool/mastotool/fyne-cross/dist/linux-amd64/mastotool.tar.xz"
        run: |
          fyne-cross \
            ${{ matrix.target.os }} \
            ${{ matrix.target.args }} \
            -name mastotool-${{ matrix.target.os }}${{ matrix.target.ext }} \
            -app-id com.github.PaulWaldo.mastotool
          ls -lR fyne-cross/dist

      - name: Archive production artifacts
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: mastotool
          path: fyne-cross/dist/${{ matrix.target.os }}*/*

  release:
    name: Create Release
    needs: artifacts
    runs-on: "ubuntu-latest"
    steps:
      - name: Download all workflow run artifacts
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3

      - run: ls -lR

      - uses: ncipollo/release-action@v1
        with:
          artifacts: mastotool/*/*
```

Comment: Regarding your second approach, the jobs are run in different runners i.e. artifacts generated in one job are not visible to the other jobs. So, you need to share those between jobs. You can upload artifacts in the first job and then download them in the second to create the release. See [Passing data between jobs in a workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/storing-workflow-data-as-artifacts#passing-data-between-jobs-in-a-workflow) for more details.

Comment: @Azeem, that is a good answer.  Working on fine-tuning the action, and I will add it to my question when it is ready.  If you want to make it an answer, I will mark it correct.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the release should only be created once all the artifacts are ready, your second approach makes more sense i.e. to divide your workflow in `artifacts` and `release` jobs.

However, jobs are run in different runners so you need to share the generated artifacts between `artifacts` and `release` jobs.

Please refer to [Passing data between jobs in a workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/storing-workflow-data-as-artifacts#passing-data-between-jobs-in-a-workflow) to do this with [upload-artifact](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact) and [download-artifact](https://github.com/actions/download-artifact) actions.